# Bootstrap3 Burger Menu displays incorrectly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the issue where the easiest way to describe it is with a picture, see below.

[image: the problem]

Now I'm not sure if it makes a difference but my nav is sort of nested inside a jumbo, here's the code.

```
<div class="jumbotron book-jumbo"
 style="background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-banner2.jpg') }}');     background-size:   cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; ">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> <!-- removed navbar-fixed-top -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>


            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="navbar-left"><a class="navbar-brand"  href="/"> <img style="height:40px; margin-top:-15px;" src="{{url_for('.static', filename='logo.png')}}"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class=""><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/book-cleaning/">Book Now</a></li>
                    <li class="phone"><a href="tel:01952 924090">01952 924090 (FREE)</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row jumbotxt">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="">
            <h1>You're 60 seconds away from you-time o'clock.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This behaviour is very odd, haven't seen anything like it before. Could anybody please point out the issue and the fix?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably the `<button>` element is too large so the three lines are displayed side by side instead of on top of each other. Two possible solutions: either decrease the `width` of the button or give to the `span`s of class `.icon-class` a `display: block;` property.

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right. Adding 'display:block;' fixes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see without your custom css but do you have any overwriting css that could touch the icon-bar class or span element?  I was able to replicate only after adding

```
.icon-bar {display:inline-block !important;}
```

From your image it looks like "inline-block" is being added somewhere to those spans.  You can see how I was able to replicate at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQVJXV

Maybe think about making a pen of your own or include your css if this doesn't solve the issue.